# Multi-master Cassandra between directly unroutable data centers

Tags: cassandra, multi-master-replication

We have three facilities, call them Main, Remote1 and Remote2, all of which have local users of an application.  Users currently hit a SQL db in Main and we're looking to move to Cassandra.  We want writes in all data centers to hit the local Cassandra nodes, not just the nodes in Main.  Servers in the Main data center can communicate with servers in Remote1 and Remote2, but there is no routing or DNS visibility between Remote1 and Remote2.

Is it possible to set up Cassandra with three data centers where some nodes cannot communicate directly with other nodes?  Is it possible to have writes from Remote1 be propagated to Main where they are pushed to Remote2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Cassandra does not support this scenario.